# Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis Website\profile.php on line 33 how to fix this thanks :)

Tags: php, mysql

`$result= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empno= '".$_SESSION['id']."'");`

Comment: If you are using an MVC framework, how comes you have code in what appears to be the project root? And if you are using CakePHP, why aren't you using `Session` or builtin ORM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: BTW, we are in 2017. Learning PHP with `mysql_query()` is like learning to drive with a steam carriage, but probably less funny :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no element named 'id' in $_SESSION. Either start a session or check the Hash's contents (print_r is your friend if you don't use an IDE)

Comment: No I can't. It's a conceptual error. I suggest reading about session management in PHPs documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CakePHP tag was a red herring, these are some issues to address:

1. Verify you are loading [session data](http://php.net/session_start).
2. Make sure you are actually writing somewhere the session data you need:

   ```
   $_SESSION['id'] = ...
   ```
3. Look up the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual) as much as needed.
4. I know you skipped previous point because if you had checked [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) you would have seen the big red warning:

   > This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

   You are wasting your energy learning a feature that no longer exists.
5. When a given array item may or may not exist, write code that handles both situations gracefully:

   ```
   if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
       // ....
   } else {
       // ....
   }
   ```
6. The proper way to inject variables into SQL is prepared statements:

   ```
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empno = ?';
   $params = [
       $_SESSION['id']
   ];
   $stmt = $your_library->function_to_prepare($sql);
   $res = $stmt->function_to_execute($params);
   ```
7. If you don't have a decent [debugger](http://xdebug.org) you can always use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) to display variables.